# I am getting "AttributeError: type object 'Observable' has no attribute 'from_'" error in python rx=3.0.1

Tags: python-3.x, rx-py

this is code from the "reactive programming with python" book that I have tried on my laptop.

```
import sys
from rx import Observable

argv = Observable.from_(sys.argv[1:])
argv.subscribe(
    on_next=lambda i: print("on_next: {}".format(i)),
    on_error=lambda e: print("on_error: {}".format(e)),
    on_completed=lambda: print("on_completed")
)
```

If I run

```
python echo1.py hello world there
```

the output should look like this:

```
on_next: hello 
on_next: world 
on_next: there 
on_completed
```

Comment: Check your RxPy version I had a similar issue and things have changed in RxPy 3.0.1

Answer (score 1):

I believe you import is the issue here as of RxPY 3.0.1 imports seem to work differently, you now import `from_` directly from `rx`.

You might want to take a look at the [Get Started](https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started.html) and the [Migration](https://rxpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html) sections in the RxPY docs they should explain far better than I could how it now works.

```
import sys
from rx import from_

argv = ops.from_(sys.argv[1:])
argv.subscribe(
    on_next=lambda i: print("on_next: {}".format(i)),
    on_error=lambda e: print("on_error: {}".format(e)),
    on_completed=lambda: print("on_completed")
)
```

Comment: Importing `from_` from `rx` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Now you don't need Observable. All operations execute in pipe.

```
import rx
from rx import operators as ops

argv = rx.from_(sys.argv[1:])

# argv.map(...).filter(...).subscribe(...) old stuff
argv.pipe(
    ops.map(...), 
    ops.filter(...)
).subscribe(...)
```

So forget about Observable object.